# Select previous element in jQuery - closest not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to select an element in jQuery but can't do it successfully. I tried prev, prevall and closest but no success.

Basically, when clicking a form, I want to update a value above my form (in a page where the forms will appear multiple times).

I tried making it work in jsfiddle there (one click should return the value above it):

http://jsfiddle.net/s7c2f/1/

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(".addshowscoreinqtip").click(function() {
    var button = $(this);      
    var curscore = button.closest('.rating-recent-text');
    var currentscore = curscore.html();
    alert(currentscore);

 });
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you format that HTML in the fiddle, I can't tell what is happening?

Comment: `.closest` searches for *ancestors* matching the selector.

Comment: Your elements are nested, and nested, and nested, you'll need to do a lot more DOM traversal than just closest() or prev().

Comment: Here's a more formatted html http://jsfiddle.net/s7c2f/2/

Comment: @Anton - It's still not valid, there are closing form tags, but no form etc ?

Comment: Not really. See the red text? It means something's wrong. Make the `<img>` self closing (`<img .../>`) and figure out where the to put a `form` opening tag.

Comment: @adeneo I didn't want to remove the things he/she had in the html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s7c2f/2/

Comment: It does not work since `.rating-recent-text` and `.clickhere` are brothers.

`closest()` method, instead, looks up on ancestry hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the HTML was huge so I randomly shortened it. One of the answrs below will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  var curscore = button.closest('.two.columns').find('.rating-recent-text');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7c2f/3/)

Answer (score 2):

`closest` selects the closest matching parent element and `prev` selects the direct previous sibling element, you can use both of them:

```
var curscore = button.closest('.tip-content')
                     .prev('.trending-container')
                     .find('.rating-recent-text');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sgN4q/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go up to common parent, `.columns` in your case. For example:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7c2f/4/)

```
 $(".clickhere").click(function() {
    var button = $(this);      
    var curscore = button.closest('.columns').find('.rating-recent-text');
    var currentscore = curscore.html();
    alert(currentscore);
 });
```